# PHP filter_var for a URL against XSS attacks

Tags: php, xss

Here is my function:

```
function is_url($url) {
    return (preg_match('#^(https?):\/\/#i', $url) && (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) !== FALSE));
}
```

And here is a nice url that it validates as true:

```
http://blah.com"onclick="alert(document.cookie)
```

Imagine if that goes into `<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">`

Are there any better URL validators with regex? Or is the URL I am testing with actually a valid URL (in which case I would need an XSS clean up function)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<del>There's this built-in [filter](http://php.net/filter):</del>

```
filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
```

This will return `false` with your example URL. If it were valid, it would return `$url`. Example:

```
glopes@nebm:~$ php -r "var_dump(filter_var('http://blah.com\"onclick=\"alert(document.cookie)', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL));"
bool(false)
```

Anyway, the solution to prevent XSS is to use `htmlspecialchars`. Since it's an attribute, you should use `ENT_QUOTES`:

```
htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_QUOTES);
```

But you should also validate the URL, because otherwise the user can include `javascript:`-like "URLs".

Comment: Ah sorry, the line was too long and I didn't read that part. But anyway, it does return false.

Comment: That's strange what happens when you run http://pastebin.com/9Yvg7Gqn for me its dumping as bool(true) ??

Comment: @fire Nop, gives `false` on both the latest 5.2 and 5.3: http://codepad.viper-7.com/gt5udu

Comment: Weird I am getting true on 5.2.6

Comment: It was fixed around Christmas 2009 which means only releases after that date will do the validation on the host part of the URL: that means 5.2.13/5.3.2 or newer.